# Mutually exclusive options with Thor

Tags: thor

Is there any way to have two mutually exclusive options with Thor? For example, I need to provide an option of a list of something. I might have an option `-l ent1 ent2 ent3 ent67`, and I might have an option `-f` which I pass a file with contents `ent1 ent2 ent3 ent67`. Can these two options be made mutually exclusive with Thor without writing extra processing code in the method?

Comment: @Mat Sorry, I thought the question is obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't found a built-in way to do this, but you could accomplish it with your own simple check. Here's an example Thor command that does what you want.

```
desc "command", "A command that does something."
option :list, aliases: 'l', type: :array
option :file, aliases: 'f'
def list
  if options[:list] && options[:file]
    puts "Use only one, --list(-l) or --file(-f)"
    exit(0)
  end
  # Place the functions of the command here
end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing in my application :)

Comment: Instead of `exit(0)`, I would `raise Thor::Error, "Use only one: --list(-l) or --file(-f)"`. That way, `$?` is set to non-zero and if it's another script invoking the Thor executable, it can properly handle the fact it provided bad input.